# Spark: how is parquet read

Tags: apache-spark, driver, parquet, snappy

A question in order to understand how spark does its job. When you use:

```
spark.read.parquet(sourcePath).{transformation}.{action}
```

How is are the parquet files read? Is it done on the driver and then dispatched to each executor? Or is each file sent to an executor, which is responsable of the reading?

If parquet is snappy compressed, where and how is uncompression done?

I wonder if parquet files may stay in the driver memory after they have been read.

Comment: This performance analysis is a good read that may help. 

https://externaltable.blogspot.com/2017/09/performance-analysis-of-cpu-intensive.html

Comment: It doesn't explain how Spark does the job, yet interesting thx